# Dijkstra's Algorithm Equal Weights

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dijkstra

I'm working on my assignment about [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), and have gotten to a point where the remaining points are:

```
B: 30 from H
C: Infinite
E: 40 from H
F: 30 from D
G: Infinite
```

Would the next point that I chose be `B` because alphabetically it comes before `F`?

Comment: In case of several nodes having the minimal currently known distance, you can choose arbitrarily. The only condition is that you always pick a node with minimal distance that hasn't been processed yet, because this way it's guaranteed that you process nodes in monotonously increasing order of distance from the source, which is what the proof of correctness for that algorithm requires.

Comment: In practice, it's generally bad to have arbitrary choices, so the work around is usually to have two distance metrics that are keeping track of the distance to the current closest node. One distance metric is the primary one and the other is secondary. If the primary one is equal, then you can use the secondary distance metric to decide which edge is closer.